# SSRS export to Excel gets rid of expanders (rendering issue?)

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

In the report portal my report looks nicely rendered, as per the below:

[image]

However, when I export it to Excel, it gets rid of the expanders and seems to group all weeks last year and this under 2018 (example below). Does anybody have any idea why this is happening?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Under column groups, click Quarter and select group properties, go to visibility and select hide.